# Getting bad interpreter error even though when using python script.py it works

Tags: python

Hello Stack Overflow Saviors,
I have the following script in python

```
#!usr/bin/env python
# Years till 100

import sys

name = sys.argv[1]
age = int(sys.argv[2])
diff = 100 -age
print name, "will be 100 in", diff
```

I wrote it using nano, then saved it as timetill100.py, used `chmod u+x timetill100.py` but when I run `./timetill100.py` I get the following error :

```
bash: ./timetill100.py: usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

but when I run `python timetill100.py andy 25` it works wonderfully.
I picked up scripting in python a few hours ago, so please tell me where I'm failing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your shebang line is wrong:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

As you had it, the script was trying to execute `usr/bin/env`, not `/usr/bin/env` :-)

Comment: Omg, I'm so stupid :'D I'll accept the answer as soon as possible